# SwiftUI Hidden ".navigationBarHidden" appearance bug

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

I have 3 windows that are connected by a NavigationLink and the NavigationBar is hidden, but I need the ability to swipe to go back, for this I use this code:

```
import SwiftUI

extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }
}

@main
struct testSheetApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                VStack{
                    NavigationLink(destination: {
                        ContentView2()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("new")
                    })
                }
            }        .navigationBarHidden(true)
            
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            VStack{
                Button(action: {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }, label: {
                    Text("back")
                })
                
                NavigationLink(destination: {
                    ContentView3()
                }, label: {
                    Text("next")
                })
            }
        }        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        
        
    }
    
    
}

struct ContentView3: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button(action: {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }, label: {
                Text("back")
            })
            
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Everything works fine with the second form, you can return with a swipe, but on the 3rd form, when you cancel the swipe, when the screen remains on the same form, a NavigationBar appears

[Bug NavigationBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxvcM.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem, you need to add to the NavigationLink, **".isDetailLink (false)"**

code snippet:

```
 NavigationLink(destination: {
                    ContentView3()
                }, label: {
                    Text("next")
                }).isDetailLink(false)
```